# Spinner data to string

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner

I have a spinner bounded with data, and I want to select it and put the string selected in a variable..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getSelectedItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) to get the currently selected item. If you've bound to an ArrayAdapter<String>, this will be the value.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: sorry i have this code:  desc_cat = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);

Comment: So you'd use desc_cat.getSelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is a plain String,

```
  mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition (pos); // Your string
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // your code here, if any 
    }
}
```