# Spinners and Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I would like to take the value of a spinner and convert it to a String to play about with.

```
    Spinner s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I thought somthing like this would work....

```
 private OnClickListener sendClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        EditText dstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destinationAddress);
        EditText dstLanguage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        String address = dstName.getText().toString();   
        String language = dstLanguage.getText().toString();

        ops.createSocketConnection(language, address);  
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.vibrate = new long[] {100};
    }};
```

Allas it does not....

I have looked at a few examples however I am not sure If they are directly related to my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedHandler = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) {
        String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        // Do whatever you want with the string
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing
    }
};
//set the spinner's listener for select event

mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what the question is, but if the issue is getting the value of a spinner, check out [Spinner data to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651402/spinner-data-to-string/5651756#5651756):

> You can use [getSelectedItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) to
>   get the currently selected item. If
>   you've bound to an
>   ArrayAdapter<String>, this will
>   be the value.

Of course, in this instance you're returning CharSequence, so you'd do

```
String strVal = getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Hi Leo, sorry if the question is a little vauge. I am attempting to pass the value currently of a spinner to a String value. With a text field I use edit text and then convert it to a String with toString. I just wanted to see if there was a way similar to this. Thanks

Comment: <spinner>.getSelectedItem().toString() will do it.